# How to hide screen informations off Android app when it goes to the background

Tags: android

Using FLAG_SECURE, when app goes to background screen info are invisible, however, with this option users cannot take a screenshot anymore.

it's there any way to remove FLAG_SECURE when app back to FOREGROUND ?

Or any other solution for this problem ?!

Answer (score 2):

You can put a black or white background in onPause and hide it in onResume if you dont need the FLAG_SECURE always active. This could prevent the window manager to exposes the screenshot in the window manager screen.

Comment: OnPause and similar lifecycle methods are called too late (the screenshot is taken already). All lifecycle methods that would hint that you're about to go into the background runs too late.